# Is it possible to turn this code into a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I was wondering whether it is possible to turn this code into a for loop.  I know that you could loop the text, however, is it possible to do something similar to the variables inputRangeCity1, inputRangeCity2 etc..

```
    System.out.print("Enter maximum cell phone connectivity distance for city 1: ");
    double inputRangeCity1 = user_input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter maximum cell phone connectivity distance for city 2: ");
    double inputRangeCity2 = user_input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter maximum cell phone connectivity distance for city 3: ");
    double inputRangeCity3 = user_input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter maximum cell phone connectivity distance for city 4: ");
    double inputRangeCity4 = user_input.nextDouble();
```

Comment: you could use an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare `inputRangeCity1`, etc as separate local variables, it is next to impossible to use a loop.

If you declare `inputRangeCity1`, etc as separate instance (or class) variables, it is *possible* to use reflection.  However, it is not a good solution ... because the code will be more complex, more verbose and fragile.

The best / simplest solution is to use an array rather than separate variables:

```
    double[] inputRangeCities = new double[NOS_CITIES];
```

and then:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= inputRangeCities.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter maximum cell phone connectivity " +
                         "distance for city " + i + ": ");
        inputRangeCities[i - 1] = user_input.nextDouble();
    }
```

If the number of cities is not known (fixed) at the point where you need to declare the variable, then you should use a `List` instead.  Otherwise, an array is better ... unless there is some other part of the application wthat would benefit from using a list.

---

If the array / collection approach is not what you need, then consider refactoring like this:

```
private double readRange(Scanner input, int cityNo) {
    System.out.print("Enter maximum cell phone connectivity " +
                     "distance for city " + i + ": ");
    return input.nextDouble();
}

...
double inputRangeCity1 = readRange(user_input, 1);
double inputRangeCity2 = readRange(user_input, 2);
double inputRangeCity3 = readRange(user_input, 3);
double inputRangeCity4 = readRange(user_input, 4);
```

It is *more lines of code* ... and I don't like it ... but it is an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list instead of individual variables.

```
List<Double> inputRangeCities = new ArrayList<Double>();

for(int i=1; i <= 4; i++)
{
     System.out.print("Enter maximum cell phone connectivity distance for city" + i);
     inputRangeCities.add(user_input.nextDouble());
}
```

You can then for example access the value for the first city as `inputRangeCities.get(0)`. Note that the index in a Java list or array always starts at 0.